# Pass UUID value as a parameter to the function

Tags: postgresql, uuid, postgresql-9.3

I have the table with some columns:

```
--table
create table testz
(
   ID uuid,
   name text
);
```

**Note**: I want to insert `ID` values by passing as a parameter to the function. Because I am generating the `ID` value
in the front end by using `uuid_generate_v4()`. So I need to pass the generated value to the function to insert
into the table

## My bad try:

```
--function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testz
(
    p_id varchar(50),
    p_name text
)
RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO testz values(p_id,p_name);
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

--EXECUTE FUNCTION
SELECT testz('24f9aa53-e15c-4813-8ec3-ede1495e05f1','Abc');
```

Getting an error:

```
ERROR:  column "id" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying
LINE 1: INSERT INTO testz values(p_id,p_name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a simple cast to make sure PostgreSQL understands, what you want to insert:

```
INSERT INTO testz values(p_id::uuid, p_name); -- or: CAST(p_id AS uuid)
```

Or (preferably) you need a function, with exact parameter types, like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testz(p_id uuid, p_name text)
RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO testz values(p_id, p_name);
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

With this, a cast may be needed at the calling side (but PostgreSQL usually do better automatic casts with function arguments than inside `INSERT` statements).

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c7811/1)

If your function is that simple, you can use [`SQL` functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) too:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testz(uuid, text) RETURNS VOID
LANGUAGE SQL AS 'INSERT INTO testz values($1, $2)';
```